# Who formulated the conjecture that the set of real parts of zeros of the Riemann zeta function is dense in $[0,1]$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

Does anyone know who formulated this conjecture related to Riemann's zeta function?

Conjecture.  The set $$\{ x :   \exists   y        \space \space  \zeta (x+iy) = 0\}$$ is dense in $[0, 1]$.

In other words the conjecture states that the real parts of the nontrivial Zeta zeros are dense in [0, 1].  Some time ago I read about this conjecture in a review paper about Riemann's Zeta function but I cannot remember the name of the author.  Other details/references appreciated.

Comment: I wonder which piece of evidence can support such a conjecture...

Comment: Weird. The more usual conjecture is that it consists of just one point.

Comment: I know , it's shocking and completely opposite to Riemann's Hypothesis but I guarantee the conjecture exists. I just can't remember who formulated it. I would also be interested in any  other details/references  related to it.

Comment: I suspect it was not so much a conjecture as a way to show just how far away we are from a proof of the Riemann Hypothesis. There is a thread somewhere here on MathOverflow about "outrageous conjectures" like this. Found the thread: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/259844/the-most-outrageous-or-ridiculous-conjectures-in-mathematics

Comment: I accept your point of view but I cannot speculate on the intent of the author that formulated this statement.  I just want to remember his name and find  any relevant references that mention his conjecture.

Comment: In the absence of any details about the author, it might help to avoid male pronouns.

Comment: In the same spirit: [The Alternative Hypothesis](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.12123) _concerns a hypothetical and unlikely picture of how zeros of the Riemann zeta function are spaced which one would like to rule out. In the Alternative Hypothesis, the renormalized distance between nontrivial zeros is supposed to always lie at a half integer._